# Prove that the representation $\Lambda^n \mathbb{C}^n$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is trivial?

Tags: lie-algebras

I try to solve the following problem:

> Prove that the representation $\Lambda^n \mathbb{C}^n$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is trivial?

Actually, I know nothing about the properties of representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, even though we know a lot about $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

However, I know $\Lambda^n \mathbb{C}^n$ is one-dimensional complex vector space, spanned by 
$$e_1\wedge\cdots \wedge e_n.$$
So maybe this is the critical point? Also, I think this may be solved by considering character? But I know nothing about the character of the exterior power of a representation...

Comment: This may be easier if you instead think about the action of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Since this is a 1-dimensional rep and $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is perfect, it is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Lie algebra action, a matrix $A$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb C)$
takes
$e_1\wedge e_2\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$ to
$$A(e_1)\wedge e_2\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n
+e_1\wedge A(e_2)\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n+\cdots+
e_1\wedge e_2\wedge\cdots\wedge A(e_n)
=\text{tr}(A)(e_1\wedge e_2\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n).$$
So if $A\in\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ it annihilates $e_1\wedge e_2\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$.

Comment: Could you explain why the equality holds? It seems not to be very obvious to me... And is it true for every representations?

Comment: I figure it out! Thank you very much!